# Bootstrap css horizontal align elements not working properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to make to the two adjacent div horizontal to each other properly, But failed because it doesn't fit in properly.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <div class="offer-horizontal">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3" style="text-align:center;">
          <img src="https://icon.uiowa.edu/help/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ICON_logo_only.png" alt="nothing" style="height:20px;width:50px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
          <span class="offer-description-horizontal" ng-bind-html="offer.description | words:15"></span>
          <p>Some really large label that will wrap to multiple lines in small screens</p>
          <div>
            <button>
              shop now
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="offer-horizontal">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3" style="text-align:center;">
          <img src="http://www.iconplc.com/icon-files/images/image-bank-component/other/icon-logo.jpg" style="height:20px;width:50px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
          <span class="offer-description-horizontal" ng-bind-html="offer.description | words:15"></span>
          <p>Some really large label that wil</p>
          <div>
            <button>
              shop now
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="offer-horizontal">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3" style="text-align:center;">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9e/Icons_logo_normal.jpg" alt="nothing" style="height:20px;width:50px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
          <span class="offer-description-horizontal" ng-bind-html="offer.description | words:15"></span>
          <p>Some really large label that will wrap to multiple lines in small screens</p>
          <div>
            <button>
              shop now
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

1st component : div with black icon

2nd component : div with green icon (less description)

3rd component : div with blue icon

Icon and Description are one component and 2 components should be side by side with same height (in desktop and tablet. In this example I have created both the components are side by side, but due to height problem of second component with green icon has less height then the third component instead of being below of 1st component it is below second component.

Basically my question is: how to adjust 2nd component with green icon such that the third component is just below the 1st component

Any help is appreciated.

JSFiddle :

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hoekuw3v/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your JSFiddle.

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/okahara/hoekuw3v/1/

It will work for small and medium sized screens. I reorganized your classes in the html and added a min-height to `offer-horizontal`.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks I want some differentiation in div while giving background color: http://jsfiddle.net/u22uwLq6/    in this fiddle and background color overlap with other components

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I understand exactly what you want? You want each `offer-horizontal` to have a background color that is different than the `body` background color? Do you want space between them?

Comment: I solved with border property : http://jsfiddle.net/snehav27/22xvnjd5/2/ Thanks for the help !!

Comment: Cool! A thick border is one way to do it :) Glad you were able to get the results you wanted

Comment: Is there any other way you know that you can do it.

Comment: You could add more divs within certain elements and you would then use the padding from bootstrap and give the new divs background. I can make a JSFiddle during my lunch break if you want.

Comment: Sure, would like to look at other ways too. :)

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/okahara/u22uwLq6/2/)

Now the padding left and right are based off of bootstraps standard 15px padding, which you can change. and the top and bottom space are based off of margin, which you can also change. When I want space between elements I tend to use `padding` that bootstrap provides and `margin`. For me its just preference :)